# What does it mean to inject an operation?

Tags: inject

Does 'injecting' an operation just mean broadcasting it to other tezos nodes, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means inserting a signed operation into the mempool, that then will be broadcasted to other nodes in the network and hopefully included by a baker in a block.